# Bash script to identify empty items in directory

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to identify empty files within a directory.  For ease of use, I plan on just saving it to the home directory and running it from there.  Note that it to NOT be recursive.  Trying to avoid the use of the find command as it can get messy.  If you have a better suggestion than test, I am all ears.

I will say that I am fairly new to bash scripting and would normally do this in Python, but am looking to keep things consistent with what we do around here.

The output should be the list of any empty files and a counter.  Below is what I have so far, but I am not returning empty files despite having numerous ones in the "test" directory.

```
fileCount=0
for item in *; do
if test -f "$item" && ! test -s "$item"
then
    fileCount=$((fileCount+1))
    echo $item
else
    continue
    fi 
done

echo "Number of empty files: " $fileCount
```

If I wanted to modify this to take an argument (user-specified directory), how might I go about this?  Below is how I have modified it, but I believe I am having an issue with my variables.

```
 fileCount=0
 echo "Please enter a directory: " 
 read directory

 for item in $directory; do
 if test -f "$item" && ! test -s "$item"
 then
     fileCount=$((fileCount+1))
     echo $item
 else
     continue
     fi 
 done

 echo "Number of empty files: " $fileCount
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 3):

`break` ends the loop, so you stop counting at the first non-empty file. You want `continue`, which goes to the next iteration of the loop.

Or you could just write:

```
if test -f "$item" && ! test -s "$item"
then
    fileCount=$((fileCount+1))
fi
```

Comment: I modified the code above, but am having an issue.  While it is taking user input, I believe it is checking against the actual raw input and not selecting the directory of my choosing.  Is that correct?

Comment: `for item in "$directory"/*`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `find` is very simple.

`find . -type f -size 0` gives you all the empty files in the current directory.

`find . -type f -size 0 | wc -l` gives you the number of empty files.

This works even with hidden files.

If you want to list empty files only within the current directory, just add `-maxdepth 1` option to find.

Comment: `find /path ..` would be a better explanation, because while he says he will put the script in `$HOME`, we don't know where he wants to search.

Comment: Would this not cause an issue in that find would work recursively?

Comment: ^Recursively.  `-maxdepth 1` is required for only the current directory and isn't supported in all versions of find.  *cough* Solaris.

Comment: Ideally, I'd run it in home, but being able to modify later to specify a directory would be a capability I would like to add in once I get things working.

Comment: You can simply replace `'.'` with `"${1:-.}"` and it will search from `'.'` if no argument is given, or from the path provided in the first argument.

Comment: Relying on `-print` can result in double-counting if your filenames contain newlines and your `find` doesn't escape them (and thereby print something *other* than the file's actual/original name). `-print0` and counting NULs is safer, or `printf '\n'` if on a platform with GNU `find`.

Comment: While this does list empty files, it does so recursively.  I need it to list empty files only within the current directory.

Comment: If you want to list empty files only within the current directory, just add `-maxdepth 1` option to find.

Answer (score 1):

```
find PATH_TO_SEARCH -maxdepth -type f -empty | nl
```

example:

```
find proj/mini/forum -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty | nl
     1  proj/mini/forum/resolv
     2  proj/mini/forum/five
     3  proj/mini/forum/0
     4  proj/mini/forum/FactorialComplexit.java
     5  proj/mini/forum/-temp.html
     6  proj/mini/forum/index.-temp.html
```

I can't see any messyness. Since in almost all cases, filenames don't span over multiple lines, while I have to admit it is possible, nl seems a good enough tool for measuring the number of empty files met.